# sharing values among files Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, python.py, and shell

Tags: python, shell, docker, docker-compose

### How do I share a value among the stack of technologies *docker*, *docker-compose*, *Python*, and *POSIX shell* for a single project?

For example, I would like to set the value `PORT` once.  **It would be nice if `PORT` was set within one file and other files would reference that value.**

However, in my *foo* project the value `PORT` must be set among several files, each of which is a parsed by different a technology:

File `foo.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PORT = 80
```

File `Dockerfile`

```
# foo
ENV PORT=80
EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

File `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: docker.corp.com/foo
  expose:
    - '80'
```

File `run.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
PORT=80
```

It is preferable to `git commit` the files "as is", e.g. no "on the fly" code generators.

Comment: Can you control the environment?  Can any of these file be built on the fly?  This is very Broad....

Comment: _Can you control the environment?_  Partially, there is a simple project that resides on my local workstation.  But I'd also like Rancher Docker service runs this project. _Can any of these file be built on the fly?_ Assume none are built on the fly.

Comment: Which of these is the rancher service running?

Comment: _Which of these is the rancher service running?_ Rancher uses the `docker-compose.yml` to then run the Docker image built by the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the easiest solution would be setting `PORT` in your local environment.

Then:

- Your python code can read the value from `os.environ`.
- You can provide the value to your container in `docker-compose` by including:

  ```
  environment:
    PORT: ${PORT}
  ```
- If you need to start a container outside of `docker-compose`, you can pass it on the `docker run` command line:

  ```
  docker run -e PORT=$PORT ...
  ```
- And of course your `run.sh` script can just reference `$PORT` directly.

Comment: I was considering this, too. It's an okay method. Unfortunately, I cannot `git commit` that in a clean way.  In my case, a Rancher Docker service has access to the git committed files, but I cannot control the Rancher instance environment in a meanginful way.

Comment: _so you can't control the environment?_ Yep. I updated my previous Comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things like filesystem paths and TCP port numbers where Docker allows picking a value when the container is run, and that value doesn't have to be the same as what's inside the image.  For the example you give of a TCP port, it's usually easier to just pick some number and not try to make it configurable at the Docker layer.

```sh
# Dockerfile
# Don't bother setting ENV PORT
EXPOSE 80
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  web:
    image: docker.corp.com/foo
  # expose: is already in the Dockerfile, but you probably need
  ports:
    - '8000:80'
      #     ^^ where this matches the image
```

You also don't need to set values at every level.  If you `EXPOSE` a port in your `Dockerfile` you don't need to also `expose:` the same port in `docker-compose.yml`; if you set an `ENV` in the `Dockerfile` you don't need to set it in shell scripts that run inside the container.

In your script itself, you'll probably be running it both inside Docker and also outside Docker for day-to-day development, so it's useful to make details like the port number, database connectivity, ... configurable there.

```python
# foo.py
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '80'))
```

The general approach I take to this in my day job is to make the defaults in the script match what a developer needs – "high" ports like 8000, the database is running on `localhost` – but in the Docker deployment reconfigure it for the different environment.

For things that aren't related to Docker settings like port numbers, there's a more general answer to the specific question you asked.  Say you have some other environment variable

```python
# The URL the service is ultimately reachable at, taking
# things like load balancers into account
EXTERNAL_URL = os.environ.get('EXTERNAL_URL', '')
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Your service will be reachable at $EXTERNAL_URL"
exec ./myscript.py
```

These variables aren't resolved until the script is ultimately run, so if you set it once in `docker-compose.yml` everyone else will be able to read it.